# How to take the @PathVariableValue and add it to the @ModelAttribute String value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have:

```
@RequestMapping
public String someMethod(final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("customer_id" + someId, customerWithThatId);
   return "redirect:showcustomer.html";    
}
```

How can I query a `customer_id_{certain_id_value}`, by taking the `certain_id_value` from the `@PathVariable`:

```
@RequestMapping
public String showCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer_id_{howToTakeTheIdFromPathVariable?}") Customer customer, @PathVariable("customerId") String customerId) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you don't need to fill `@ModelAttribute` from `@PathVariable`. You need to get `id` from there, and then get model from the database. Something like the following:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@RequestMapping("/show/customer/customer_id_{customerId}")
public String showCustomer(@PathVariable("customerId") long customerId) {
    Customer customer = customerRepository.get(customerId);
    ......
}
```

Comment: I need to take the value from the flash scoped attributes, not from the database...long story

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 3.1 parameters annotated with `@PathVariable` are exposed to the model automatically so there is no need for special treatment.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7543

Same goes for `RedirectAttributes` flash scoped attributes.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

> After the redirect, flash attributes are automatically added to the model of the controller that serves the target URL.